# Inserting to database SQL Server Compact 3.5 windows phone

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-phone-7, insert

When I try to insert data into my database, `SubmitChanges()` throws an exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I have tried reinstalling the app and reimporting the database context. What have I done wrong here?

```
using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(ConnectionString))
{
    var monthBud = ((ListPickerItem)monthCat.SelectedItem).Content;

    Budgets budgeting = new Budgets();
    budgeting.MonthBud = monthBud.ToString();
    budgeting.YearBud = yearInput.ToString();
    budgeting.BudgetBud = Math.Round(float.Parse(budgetInput.Text), 2);

    context.Budgets.InsertOnSubmit(budgeting);
    context.SubmitChanges();

    //  MessageBox.Show(budgetInput.ToString());
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Additional note: I have commented out the line budgeting.YearBud = yearInput.ToString(); and it works. Is there something wrong with that line? Below is the XAML for that line.

```
<TextBox Name="yearInput" 
                 InputScope="Number" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"  
                 BorderBrush="Silver" 
                 />
```

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

This is the error when it breaks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are actually creating a database. Try adding this

```
if (!context.DatabaseExists())
{
    context.CreateDatabase();
}
```

Comment: I have fixed it by changing the type of the yearBud to integer. It works now. Thanks for helping